# How can I declare two classes so they can be passed to the same function?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

Given the following two classes

```
public class LocalFoo {

}

public class RemoteFoo {

}
```

Both of these classes SHOULD have similar properties :

```
public string strBar{ get; set; }
public int intBar{ get; set; }
```

The difference being how those properties are set and read - in the former case the properties are handled locally - by the program. In the latter, the properties are read and written directly from and two a DataTable read from a Database.

I know that Inheritance is going to have to happen here but that's where I'm getting stuck.

For example, if I declare a method `TakesFoo` :

```
public void takesFoo( Foo bar ){
    /*Magic Happens Here*/
}
```

I want that to be able to call that method with an object of either type `LocalFoo` or `RemoteFoo`.

I know I could write an abstract class Foo :

```
public abstract class Foo{
}
```

and have both LocalFoo and RemoteFoo inherit from it but there's a caveat - I have another abstract class which I need RemoteFoo to inherit that is used making it easier to read/write to/from DataTables -

```
public abstract class DRHelper : IEquatable<DRHelper>, IDisposable {
}
```

My initial instinct is to make Foo an interface but I don't know if that will work and I was hoping someone could give me some direction on how I should handle this problem.

Comment: Interfaces. The answer is interfaces :) However, you should be careful that you are not inheriting in order to re-use code. That is not an appropriate use of inheritance (encapsulation is normally preferred for code-reuse).

Comment: *"My initial instinct is to make Foo an interface"* Do that.

Comment: @Codor `Foo` doesn't need to inherit from anything - RemoteFoo needs to inherit `DRHelper`.

Comment: An Interface is perfect here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an IFoo interface that has:

```
string strBar{ get; set; }
int intBar{ get; set; }
```

class LocalFoo and class RemoteFoo would both need to implement the IFoo interface.

then change your method as:

```
public void takesFoo( IFoo bar ){
    /*Magic Happens Here*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should use [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

It allows you to avoid `if(bar is LocalFoo)` code.

```
    public abstract class Foo
    {
        public abstract void Accept(IVisitor visitor);
    }

    public class LocalFoo : Foo
    {
        public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }
    }

    public class RemoteFoo : Foo
    {
        public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }
    }

    public interface IVisitor
    {
        void Visit(LocalFoo foo);
        void Visit(RemoteFoo foo);
    }

    public class Visitor : IVisitor
    {
        public void Visit(RemoteFoo foo)
        {
            /*Magic Happens Here*/
        }

        public void Visit(LocalFoo foo)
        {
            /*Magic Happens Here*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: Except that my code doesn't care whether or not the incoming object is a `RemoteFoo` or a `LocalFoo` as long as it has the properties `strBar` and `intBar`.

Comment: It means than Joe's answer is right answer - just use an interface

Comment: I know - I had to wait for the time to elapse to mark it correct.